# Regular Expression allow only numbers, commas and dashes

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm trying to come up with a Data Annotation regular expression to match the following formats.

34

38-30

100,25-30

4-5,5,1-5

Basically the expression should only allow **numbers**, **-(dash)** and **,(comma)** in any order

I tried following but couldn't get it working.

```
[RegularExpression(@"(0-9 .&'-,]+)", ErrorMessage ="Lot numbers are invalid.")]
```

Comment: `[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\-,]+$", ...]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your use case is having a CSV list of numbers, or *ranges* of numbers (identified as a number followed by a dash followed by another number).  We can use the following regex:

```
[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?)*
```

This regex matches a number, followed by an optional dash and another number, that quantity then followed by comma and another similar term, any number of times.

In the demo below I added anchors on both sides of the regex.  Whether you need to do this depends on how you plan to use the pattern.

## Demo

Comment: Your regex is not working properly. He said he wants it to work in any order. Last two lines are not detected as valid.

Comment: @Spectarion Which "last two lines?"  If we add anchors to my pattern, it works.  Without anchors, then a partial match could happen on a string which logically should fail.

Comment: I got it now. You assumed that he needs to work with a CSV list of numbers and you made it to work properly with CSV. I just assumed he needs a regex to allow only those 3 characters: number, dash and comma.

Answer (score 8):

It's `^[0-9,-]*$`. Check out this **[demo](https://regex101.com/r/krVsFx/1)**.